# How to use Excel VBA to update MP3 file properties for MP3 files where Bit rate is 128 kbps

Tags: excel, vba

I am Setting Track Position for a group of MP3's. For MP3's where Bit rate is 64 kbps this Sub works fine; yet for a MP3's where Bit rate is 128 kbps this Sub works fine until the 2nd iteration of the Do While Loop and errors out on the line

```
.LoadFromFile MyFileFullName, False
```

with error message:

> Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)'
> Automation error
> The remote procedure call failed

Have you ever seen this before in Excel VBA? How to fix? Below is the simple code for the Sub:

```
Sub SetMP3FileProperties()

   Dim id3 As Object
   Dim MyFileFullName As String ' full path & file name

   Dim MyNumber As Integer

   Set id3 = CreateObject("CDDBControlRoxio.CddbID3Tag")
   sDir = "C:\Users\BradPC\Music\AbbeyRoad\"

   sFileName = Dir$(sDir & "\*.mp3")
   MyNumber = 1 'Mid(sFileName, 1, 2)

   Do While sFileName > ""
       MyFileFullName = sDir & "\" & sFileName

       With id3
           .LoadFromFile MyFileFullName, False '‹-- here's where it errors on 2nd iteration of the Loop

           .TrackPosition = MyNumber
           .SaveToFile MyFileFullName
       End With

       MyNumber = MyNumber + 1
       sFileName = Dir$
   Loop

   ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at your object this code relies upon Roxio which is closed source proprietary software. You're going to have to rely upon them for documentation on how to use their object. To do that: Buy their software and contact support: https://www.roxio.com/en/

Comment: Besides what HackSlash recommended, what you can do is checking the value of `MyFileFullName` in case of the error. What is it?

Comment: MyFileFullName is "C:\Users\BradPC\Music\AbbeyRoad\02_Hold_on_Im_Comin.mp3." That is a valid path and file name. Not finding CDDBControlRoxio.CddbID3Tag or cddbcontrolroxio.dll anywhere on the Roxio site.  I started a chat and Roxio tech support said cddbcontrolroxio.dll is not their application. So hit a dead end with Roxio. 
 Is there any other way to update MP3 file properties? Can a Windows Powershell or DOS script update MP3 file properties?

Comment: If there is really a dot **after** your file extension `"C:\Users\BradPC\Music\AbbeyRoad\02_Hold_on_Im_Comin.mp3."` then this could probably be an issue. • Why don't you just use one of the good old ID3 editors (eg https://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) that are available on the internet. Almost everyone can extract track numbers from file names and write them automatically. No need to write a VBA code for that then.

Comment: That was not a dot after file extension "C:\Users\BradPC\Music\AbbeyRoad\02_Hold_on_Im_Comin.mp3." but a period to indicate the end of the sentence (I shouldn't be so worried about correct grammar here).  At any rate Mp3tag editor worked brilliantly. It assigned sequential track numbers just as I was trying to do, so no need to write custom code for that.  Thanks for suggesting Mp3tag editor; it's a spiffy tool and user friendly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers (off-topic).

Comment: how do I close the question?

Answer (score 0):

Mp3tag editor (eg mp3tag.de/en/index.html) can assign sequential track numbers for a group of MP3 files so no need to write custom code to do it.

- Highlight your group of MP3 files
- Select the Auto-numbering Wizard (button at top with a 1-2 on it)